# Distribution of Integral involving wiener process

Tags: integration, brownian-motion

Given $W(t)$ as a standard Wiener process, i.e. $W(t) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,t)$.

Prove the following statement:

$$\int_{0}^{1}tW(t)dt \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\frac{2}{15})$$

Comment: This isn't convergence, you're just asking about how to show what the distribution of this variable *is*.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It's easy enough to see that the Riemann sums of this thing will always be normally distributed with mean zero, and will converge almost surely to the given r.v. So, if one could just show that the variances of these Riemann sums converge to $\frac{2}{15}$, then we'd be done. It would be an unelegant but functional proof. I think that Riemann sums with mesh $2^{-n}$ may work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following proof is very unelegant/non-clever/direct/bruteforce, but it works nonetheless:

Define $X:= \int_0^1 tW_t dt$. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define $$X_n=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n}\; W_{\frac{k}{n}}$$ Notice that $X_n$ is just the Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 tW_t dt$ with respect to the partition $(\frac{0}{n},\frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n},...,\frac{n}{n})$. Since $(W_t)$ is a.s. continuous, we know that $X_n \to X$ a.s.

Now, there is a theorem which states that if $X_n$ is a collection of normally distributed random variables with mean $\mu_n$ and variance $\sigma_n^2$, and if $\mu_n \to \mu$ and $\sigma_n^2 \to \sigma^2$, **and** $X_n \to X$ a.s, then $X$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

Now, it is clear that the $X_n$ are normally distributed with mean $0$, so all we need to do is to prove that their variances converge to $\frac{2}{15}$. For this, notice that

$var(X_n) = var \bigg(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n}\; W_{\frac{k}{n}}\bigg)$

$=\frac{1}{n^4}var\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n k\; W_{\frac{k}{n}}\bigg)$

$=\frac{1}{n^4} \bigg(\sum_{k=1}^nvar\big(k\;W_{\frac{k}{n}}\big)+2\sum_{ i<j} cov\big(i\;W_{\frac{i}{n}},j\;W_{\frac{j}{n}}\big)\bigg)$

$=\frac{1}{n^4} \bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^3}{n}+2\sum_{ i<j} \frac{i^2j}{n}\bigg)$

$=\frac{1}{n^5} \bigg(\sum_{k=1}^nk^3+2\sum_{ j=2}^n \sum_{i=1}^{j-1} i^2j\bigg)$

$=\frac{1}{n^5} \bigg(\frac{1}{4}n^2(n+1)^2+\frac{1}{60}n(n^2-1)(8n^2+5n-2)\bigg)$

Now, as $n$ gets large, this last expression approaches $\frac{1}{60}\cdot 8=\frac{2}{15}$, which completes the proof.

(Note: Another, less direct way to compute those complicated summations is to associate them to Riemann sums of functions we know about.)

Comment: One more question about the result:
$$2\sum_{j=2}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{j-1} i^2j = \frac{1}{60}n(n^2-1)(8n^2+5n-2)$$
How do you derive this result?

Comment: Use the formulas for sums of consecutive powers: http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~erowland/sumsofpowers.html

Comment: A better way to do this, is to realize that $\frac{2}{n^5}\sum_{i<j} i^2j=\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i<j} \big(\frac{i}{n}\big)^2 \big(\frac{j}{n}\big)$ is just a Riemann sum for $2\int_0^1 \int_0^t s^2t \; ds  dt=\frac{2}{15}$.